# Is Riak a viable choice for dynamic network environments?

Tags: riak

We are considering Riak for use in an embedded device context (embedded Linux) where devices are dynamically addressed (DHCP).

Is this a viable choice?

We can assume that appropriate auto-discovery protocols are in place to enable devices to discover each other. Upon joining the network, a device would obviously need to do a `riak-admin cluster join <other device>`. Other than this, would Riak be capable of handling devices leaving and re-joining the network on a fairly non-frequent basis? Or, does it play much more nicely in a statically-addressed environment?

Answer (score 1):

DHCP doesn't necessarily mean the device has to join when it boots.  If the node names are resolvable via DNS or hosts file, and the listeners are configured to 0.0.0.0, the Riak nodes should communicate quite happily even if their IPs change on reboot.